# scrollRectToVisible doesn't work with keyboard and (next/previous)toolbar. Please see the picture

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

scrollRectToVisible doesn't work with keyboard and (next/previous/done)toolbar. Please see the picture.

```
[scrollview scrollRectToVisible: textFieldRect animated:YES];
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method scrollRectToVisible: is doing the correct thing. It's scrolling the view to the point where the CGRect specified is within the visible section of the view. **But**, here's the thing - you're positioning another view over the top of the scroll view, so a part of the scroll view's visible area is obscured. The scroll view doesn't know about this, it only knows about it's visible section independant of any other views.

A solution to this may be to offset your *textFieldRect CGRect* by a given amount, to get the scroll view to scroll a little further in a given direction. You could, for example, use the size of the onscreen keyboard to calculate this offset, or perhaps the size of the translucent view that can be seen in your screenshot?